# C++ 17: Makefile flags for pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, makefile

Having

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++17
CXXFLAGS += -I inc/ -lpthread -pthread

SRC =   ...
OBJ =   $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

NAME    =   ...

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    g++ $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    g++ $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)
```

I tried with -`pthread` alone, with -`lpthread` alone, and both.
Still getting the following error on compilation:

```
g++ src/Main.o src/Logger.o src/handlers/MasterPacketHandler.o src/handlers/SlavePacketHandler.o src/netwotk/AbstractPacketHandler.o src/netwotk/NetworkBuffer.o src/netwotk/NetworkClient.o src/netwotk/NetworkProtocol.o src/netwotk/NetworkServer.o src/process/SlaveWorker.o src/process/Task.o src/process/TaskDispatcher.o src/process/ThreadPoolExecutor.o src/process/Timer.o src/protocol/DestroyProcessMessage.o src/protocol/FreePlaceMessage.o src/protocol/SearchRequestMessage.o src/protocol/SearchResultMessage.o -o plazza
src/Main.o : Dans la fonction « std::__shared_mutex_pthread::unlock() » :
Main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt22__shared_mutex_pthread6unlockEv[_ZNSt22__shared_mutex_pthread6unlockEv]+0x14) : référence indéfinie vers « pthread_rwlock_unlock »
src/Main.o : Dans la fonction « std::__shared_mutex_pthread::lock_shared() » :
Main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt22__shared_mutex_pthread11lock_sharedEv[_ZNSt22__shared_mutex_pthread11lock_sharedEv]+0x14) : référence indéfinie vers « pthread_rwlock_rdlock »
src/netwotk/NetworkClient.o : Dans la fonction « std::__shared_mutex_pthread::lock() » :
NetworkClient.cpp:(.text._ZNSt22__shared_mutex_pthread4lockEv[_ZNSt22__shared_mutex_pthread4lockEv]+0x14) : référence indéfinie vers « pthread_rwlock_wrlock »
src/netwotk/NetworkClient.o : Dans la fonction « std::thread::thread<std::thread& (NetworkClient::*)(bool), NetworkClient*, bool>(std::thread& (NetworkClient::*&&)(bool), NetworkClient*&&, bool&&) » :
NetworkClient.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IM13NetworkClientFRS_bEJPS1_bEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IM13NetworkClientFRS_bEJPS1_bEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x2a) : référence indéfinie vers « pthread_create »
src/netwotk/NetworkServer.o : Dans la fonction « std::thread::thread<std::thread& (NetworkServer::*)(bool), NetworkServer*, bool>(std::thread& (NetworkServer::*&&)(bool), NetworkServer*&&, bool&&) » :
NetworkServer.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IM13NetworkServerFRS_bEJPS1_bEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IM13NetworkServerFRS_bEJPS1_bEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x2a) : référence indéfinie vers « pthread_create »
src/process/ThreadPoolExecutor.o : Dans la fonction « std::thread::thread<void (ThreadPoolExecutor::*)(), ThreadPoolExecutor*>(void (ThreadPoolExecutor::*&&)(), ThreadPoolExecutor*&&) » :
ThreadPoolExecutor.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IM18ThreadPoolExecutorFvvEJPS1_EEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IM18ThreadPoolExecutorFvvEJPS1_EEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x24) : référence indéfinie vers « pthread_create »
src/process/Timer.o : Dans la fonction « std::thread::thread<void (Timer::*)(), Timer*>(void (Timer::*&&)(), Timer*&&) » :
Timer.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IM5TimerFvvEJPS1_EEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IM5TimerFvvEJPS1_EEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x24) : référence indéfinie vers « pthread_create »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:28 : la recette pour la cible « plazza » a échouée
make: *** [plazza] Erreur 1
```

It's a french compiler :/ But it says undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock` and `pthread_create`.. 
My lib `pthread` is well installed, do I get this error due of using `shared_mutex` from c++ 17 ?

Comment: Libraries should not be part of the flags. You want something like `g++ flagshere myprog.cpp -lpthread -o myprog`

Comment: You only need `-pthread` and you need to add `$(CXXFLAGS)` to your link command

Comment: @Galik The compile command. `-pthread` is a compiler flag.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes you are right, I think it should be added to both?

Comment: @Galik Actually it seems to be both a preprocessor option and a link option...

Comment: @juanchopanza It is a compiler flag but it is potentially useful for both compiling and linking. When linking throught the compiler it tells GCC to add the correct libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `-pthread`.

Also `CXXFLAGS` only adds itself to *implicit rules*, if you make an *explicit rule* you need to add it yourself.

```
$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)
```